# mobile html5 input type="x" vs custom mobile controls

Tags: usability, mobile, controls, html5

There has been some back and forth with the developers and the design team over building controls that match the design vs using mobile html5 standard controls for datepickers and timepickers for a mobile app I am working on.

**What all should you consider when determining whether to design your own controls, use third party controls, or using the basic html inputs which would be formatted by the client browser based on type?** We would suffer some loss of functionality by using the standard controls, but the developers argue that the maintainability and performance advantages would greatly outweigh any loss functionality.

[example of standard mobile HTML controls](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-forms-and-input-types)

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider:

- needs of the users
- familiarity of the control by the users
- needs of the product
- what the native controls provide vs.
- what off-the-shelf 3rd party controls provide vs.
- what custom controls provide vs.
- all of the above in terms of what is better for the

  - timeline
  - budget
  - maintenance
- all combined with what works best for the particular process your teams work within.

In other words, it all depends. On a lot of factors.